# How can I use a Condvar with a RwLock?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have several threads waiting on the same `Condvar` associated with data wrapped inside a `RwLock`. I'd like to call `Condvar::wait` and check a condition after holding the write lock to the data, but it seems `Condvar::wait` only accepts `MutexGuard` as an argument. Since there are many other parts that use this data as a read-only variable, I can't simply replace `RwLock` with `Mutex`.

How should I use `Condvar` together with `RwLock`-wrapped data?

Comment: Performing a Google search for "rwlock condvar" points to [Using RwLock and CondVars in Rust](https://tutorialedge.net/rust/using-rwlocks-and-condvars-rust/) as the very first solution. It does not seem like you have put a lot of effort into answering your own question.

Comment: @Shepmaster I read that article before writing this question, but I think it only explains how to use RwLock and Condvar separately. My question is about how to use them "together".

Comment: Hmm. An unfortunate title for that article, then.

Answer (score -1):

See https://github.com/Amanieu/parking_lot/issues/165 for an example of using a `CondVar` with a `RwLockGuard`.

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the question. Absent any other information, the OP is most likely asking about the standard library. parking_lot is not the standard library.